# How to make a UILocalNotification like iOS5 embbed Weather Notification in NotificationCenter

Tags: ios, notifications

first, it can not be closed unless you shut it down in settings/notification

second, simple UILocalNotification can just show a string text in NotificationCenter, but weather notification can show much more complex

three, simple UILocalNotification can just be clicked, and active the app, but weather notification can be slided to show two different views, week view and today view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till today (iOS 5.0.1) is not possible. There are not public API for doing that.
Some "insiders" claim it will be possible in future (and I also hope so of course).